# Groovy BigInteger to string

Tags: string, groovy, biginteger

I am using

```
i = value.toBigInteger()
i.toString(32).toUpperCase()
```

to convert a 16 digit 'number' to characters for use in a serial

Is there any way to force this to use the A-Z + 2-7 notation rather than 0-9 + A-V??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to re-implement the way `BigInteger.toString( radix )` works (with Java 7, it calls `java.math.Conversion.bigInteger2String` which can be [found here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/Conversion.java.html) -- and as you can see, would be a large amount of work)

Another would be to use Groovy 1.7.3 and the new tr function to simply replace the chars in your string with those you want instead:

```
str.tr( '0-9A-V', 'A-Z0-7' )
```

Comment: Thats a fantastic Groovy method. Thanks.
I will need to wait for the plug-in to Filemaker to be updated to this version then I can test it out...

Comment: mrhaki covered some usages of it here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/06/groovy-goodness-text-translation.html